# Displaying subfigures of different aspect ratio to look same aspect ratio

Tags: graphics, subfloats, eps, gnuplot, epstopdf

I have some figures that came out from gnuplot that I would like to display. The only difference between them is that one has a legend and the other one does not. So although they have the same size (the whole picture) they look like different because of the legend. I am currently plotting them with  `\subfloat` and I would like to know if there is a way to make them look almost identical in size:

```
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-1:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[scale=0.6, width=0.6\textwidth]{./case1.eps}  
    }
    \hfill
    \subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-2:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{./case1_1.eps}
    }
    \caption{Dummy figure}
    \label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}
```

And this is more or less how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: With gnuplot, did you try to adjust canvas size without including legend?.

Comment: For the readers: [Unique key and same size of graphs using multiplots](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21206351/2604213)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find no way but to manually set the height of both to some fixed length and then control the width of the second one (or the first one) until the output look *right.*

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-1:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,width=0.6\textwidth]{./case1.eps}  
    }
    \hfill
    \subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-2:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,width=0.65\textwidth]{./case1_1.eps}
    }
    \caption{Dummy figure}
    \label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}
```

As you can see we could try to put in some automation (measure the height of teh first one, use this height for the second one or some such) in the process, but the presence of legend in the second one acts as a deterrent.

*(I wish I could come up with a more intelligent answer.)*